# How the could Deluminator work the way it's shown in the movies?

Tags: harry-potter

Dumbledore's Deluminator extinguishes a lamp, and then allows it to be restored.

I can buy the idea that it would work on an electric lamp as a concept.

BUT!!!

The way they visualized it in the *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* movie seems all wrong - it takes the "light" from the lamp and makes it fly towards the Deluminator, and the lamp grows dark.

The way they visualized it was as if the light was taken off the lamp - which would work for an **burning** (oil/candle) lamps, but completely breaks down on Electric lamps.

For electric, you take away the current light, and electricity keeps flowing through and generating **more** light - unlike older lamps where you take away the burning fire and nothing will keep burning till you light the fire again.

The only correct way to visualize deluminator on electric lamp would be to show some sort of dampening magic field descending **onto** the lamp, not the light being sucked out of it.

So why did they do it? George Lucas School of Physics? Or some explained in-Universe reason?

I'd strongly prefer canon/in-universe/word-of-god explanation if one exists. "Books do it differently" is quite acceptable as books are more canonical than movies.

Comment: Sorry, but I think the answer is simple, if unsatisfying:  Magic.  Magic doesn't always seem to pay attention to, much less obey, the rules of physics.  Basically the Deluminator takes the property of producing light away, the returns it; the fact that this makes no physics sense is entirely irrelevant.  You can try to justify it with the generation of a localized warp field or something.. but the answer is just "It's Magic!"

Comment: That's the way it's described in the books too.

Comment: @keith - let me rephrase. If I'm a visual designer for HP movie, and I need to imagine how Deluminator will be done in a movie, the way that does NOT break the suspension of disbelief most is "drop a dampening darkness sphere on the light". Why did the movie designers make an opposite choice?

Comment: One way this could work would be if the Deluminator took the filament from the bulb.

Comment: Well, you could think of it as a form of Light Ventriloquism -- It's still being produced on the bulb, but the actual output of light is going to somewhere else.  Any number of magical explanations are possible; a little tiny, invisible, vanishing closet type item; the pair appears is created by the click, one encloses the light, the other then floats back to the deliminator.  Honestly, though, I think the target audience was mostly expected to simply assume it's "Magic" and not thing about it any further.

Comment: @Xantec - that makes the most sense

Comment: @Keith H Weston. Light Ventriloquism - nice!

Comment: @Xantec Not enough. Ron uses the deluminator in the first part of the 7th movie to turn off the lights of the coffee shop, which were fluorescent, and those don't have a filament.

Comment: @Janoma In that case it captures the gas in the bulb. Or perhaps in both cases the Deluminator is capturing the electrons.

Comment: @Xantec Yep, that seems more likely. George Lucas School of Physics all over again :-)

Comment: @b_jonas - Philosopher's Stone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting a few comments together, it seems like "it's just magic" is the common explanation. However, @DVK's point is being missed here (and maybe this question would be better in a "making movies" Q&A web site).

I think the director and/or visual artists chose to represent the deluminator in such a way that it would be clear that the source of light no longer displays any light (regardless of whether light is still being produced or not) *until* it is (magically) restored **by using the deluminator again**. That would be the most important feature.

Thus, a bright *something* flying toward the deluminator shows it to be capable of *capturing* and *storing* the light, which implies there is an **interaction with the light itself**, not just the source (candle, lamp, etc.). A charm *surrounding* the source to block the light would not be enough, since there is no interaction with the light there. That would look more like turning off the light with a button, not with magic.

The one difference I find with the book is the "little pop", which in the first movie is a soft swooshing noise:

> He found what he was looking for in his inside pocket. It seemed to be a silver cigarette lighter. He flicked it open, held it up in the air, and clicked it. The nearest street lamp **went out with a little pop**. He clicked it again — the next lamp flickered into darkness. Twelve times he clicked the Put-Outer, until the only lights left on the whole street were two tiny pinpricks in the distance, which were the eyes of the cat watching him.

By the way, +1 to the question for the George Lucas School of Physics. Of all justifications, that one is the most likely.